# Ruby select latest duplicated values from an array of hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Let say I have this kind of array

```
a = [
    {key: "cat", value: 1},
    {key: "dog", value: 2},
    {key: "mouse", value: 5},
    {key: "rat", value: 3},
    {key: "cat", value: 5},
    {key: "rat", value: 2},
    {key: "cat", value: 1},
    {key: "cat", value: 1}
]
```

Let say I have this array, and want to get only the latest value found for "cat".

I know how to select all of them

like

```
a.select do |e|
   e[:key] == "cat"
end
```

But I'm looking for a way to just get a selection of the last 3

desired result would be

```
[
    {key: "cat", value: 5},
    {key: "cat", value: 1},
    {key: "cat", value: 1}
]
```

thanks!

Comment: `a.select { |e| e[:key] == "cat" }.last(3)` would work.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment on the question @Stefan suggested:

```
a.select { |e| e[:key] == "cat" }.last(3)
```

Provided `a` is not too large that is likely what you should use. However, if `a` is large, and especially if it contains many elements (hashes) `h` for which `h[:key] #=> "cat"`, it likely would be more efficient to iterate backwards from the end of the array and terminate ("short-circuit") as soon as three elements `h` have been found for which `h[:key] #=> "cat"`. This also avoids the construction of a potentially-large temporary array (`a.select { |e| e[:key] == "cat" }`).

---

One way to do that is as follows.

```
a.reverse_each.with_object([]) do |h,arr|
  arr.insert(0,h) if h[:key] == "cat"
  break arr if arr.size == 3
end
  #=> [{:key=>"cat", :value=>5},
  #    {:key=>"cat", :value=>1},
  #    {:key=>"cat", :value=>1}]
```

---

See [Array#reverse_each](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse_each), [Enumerator#with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_object) and [Array#insert](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-insert). Note that because  `reverse_each` and `with_object` both return enumerators, chaining them produces an enumerator as well:

```
a.reverse_each.with_object([])
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: [{:key=>"cat", :value=>1},
  #   ...
  #   {:key=>"cat", :value=>1}]:reverse_each>:with_object([])>
```

---

It might be ever-so-slightly faster to replace the block calculation with

```
arr << h if h[:key] == "cat"
break arr.reverse if arr.size == 3
```

---

If `a` contains fewer elements `h` for which `h[:key] #=> "cat"` an array `arr` will be returned for which `arr.size < 3`. It therefore is necessary to confirm that the array returned contains three elements.

This check must also be performed when @Stefan's suggested code is used, as (for example)

```
a.select { |e| e[:key] == "cat" }.last(99)
  #=> [{:key=>"cat", :value=>1},
  #    {:key=>"cat", :value=>5},
  #    {:key=>"cat", :value=>1},
  #    {:key=>"cat", :value=>1}]
```